# Correct way to obtain Travis CI build URL

Tags: travis-ci

What is the correct way to obtain the build URL?

Having `TRAVIS_BUILD_ID` it's possible to obtain a build URL, i.e. `https://travis-ci.org/$TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG/builds/$TRAVIS_BUILD_ID`. However, I don't know whether the build comes from .org or .com version.

Will .org build URL redirect to .com? If not, is there a way to differentiate .org build from .com via environment variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TravisCI has an issue on github for that, not yet implemented https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/8935

Comment: Looks like they have implemented the feature, the variable is: $TRAVIS_BUILD_WEB_URL